# Accessing form values from pure html forms in django views

Tags: python, html, django

I am New to Django. I have an HTML form in a template file and want pass only two integers to a view function. I read the form and Widgets documentation, but its too complex, and I was not able to get it. I have strong belief you all have better idea. Is it possible to use CGI?

**HTML Template:**

```
<form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/view/" method = "get" target="_blank">
   <input type = "number" name = "Emp_ID">
   <input type="number" name="Year" min="2013" max="2020" value = "2013">
   <input type="submit" value="Run">
</form>
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def run_html(request):
    return HttpResponse('i want to use Emp_ID & Year value here')
```

Comment: I am not able to write code as code style but indentation and syntax is write

Comment: Thanks Daniel, How did you did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values from the `request.GET` dict:

```
emp_id = request.GET['Emp_ID']
year = request.GET['Year']
```

Comment: I recommend using ``request.GET.get('Emp_ID', 'default value')`` to avoid a KeyError. And btw, ``http://127.0.0.1:8080`` shouldn't be hardcoded in your (TS) template.